# How to retrieve telemetry for customer’s all devices from Thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

If I have this kind of thingsboard entities
There are Device D1,D2 and Customer C1

First time, I assigned D1 device to C1 customer

--> D1-C1

and later I unassigned C1 from D1, and I assigned D2 device to C1 customer.

--> D2-C1

then is it possible to check that customer's all telemetry C1 used?
In this case I want to retrieve C1 customer's data : all telemetry from Device D1, D2 (please see attached image)

Actually I don't know how to retrieve all those data from many devices. should I use rule chain or rest api?

[imgae](https://img1.daumcdn.net/thumb/R1280x0/?scode=mtistory2&fname=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.kakaocdn.net%2Fdn%2FbnQGZM%2FbtrRMcPROYT%2F3mIjlJdPkpWRBp0PPOnsq1%2Fimg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule Chain would help you if each device has unique set of telemetry names. In such case every time when new data comes to server you could redirect it from device to customer using *Change originator node*

In your case try to use two-step REST calls:

1. [Get list of customer's devices](https://demo.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui/#/device-controller/getCustomerDevicesUsingGET)
2. [Get telemetry for each device](https://demo.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui/#/telemetry-controller/getTimeseriesUsingGET).